# Увеличить ширину полосы прокрутки на сайте

Tags: css

Как увеличить ширину полосы прокрутки для всей страницы или для отдельного `div`-a? Стандартная полоса слишком узкая для использования на устройствах с сенсорными экранами, возникла необходимость увеличения ширины скроллбара. Возможно ли это реализовать каким-то способом?

Comment: а зачем нужна полоса прокрутки на устройствах с сенсорным экраном?

Comment: http://diokuz.github.io/baron/  вот плагинчик для костомизации скролл бара

Comment: http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/  вот ещё один , откроешь демо и сразу видно как он из тонкого в толстенный скроллбар превращается при наведении

Comment: https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin  и вот последний - ваще классный

Answer (score 1):

Управление видом скроллбара не входит в спецификацию CSS.

В браузерах с движком Webkit (Chrome, Opera) [можно настроить скроллбар](https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/), но на других браузерах не работает.

Можно поискать решения блоков с прокруткой на JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}
```